# Export Mailbox Size and Archive Size to the same file

Tags: exchange, powershell, mailbox, export

I need to export mailbox Size and Archive size to the same csv file.

I know to export the mailbox size I need to use **Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | select-object Displayname,totalitemsize | export-csv .\filename.csv**

to get archive size I need to use  **Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics -archive | select-object totalitemsize | export-csv .\filename.csv**

I need to know how to marge between this two commands.

Thank in advance.
Avraham.

Comment: Try Get-Help Export-csv -Online in powershell. And then look after Parameter -NoClobber. Is it really faster to post a question than to take a quick look at the parameters of used commands?

Answer (score 2):

I think a hash table it what you're after

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/15/automatically-create-a-powershell-hash-table-10-15-11.aspx

Basically you define a table, eg: MailboxName, ActiveSize, ArchiveSize

Create a loop, get $This value from $There . $That from $Here

Rinse  and repeat

Edit:
I haven't tested this, but should give the basic idea

```
$objTABLE = @()
ForEach ($iMailbox in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize "Unlimited"))
{
    $objTABLE += New-Object psobject -Property @{MailboxName=$(Get-Mailbox -Idendity $iMailbox | Select DisplayName); ActiveSize=$(Get-MailboxStatistics -Idendity $iMailbox | select totalitemsize); ArchiveSize=$(Get-MailboxStatistics -Archive | select-object totalitemsize)}
}


$objTABLE | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer it helped me a little to build the report I needed.

This is the report I needed:

```
$Mailboxes = @(get-Mailbox)
$report = @()

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
    {
        $mailboxonly = Get-Mailbox $Mailbox
        $mailboxstate = Get-Mailbox $Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics
        $mailboxstateA = Get-Mailbox $Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics -archive

        $inpObj = New-Object PSObject
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Display Name" -Value $mailboxstate.DisplayName 
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PrimarySmtpAddress" -Value $mailboxonly.PrimarySmtpAddress
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Database" -Value $mailboxstate.Database
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MailboxSize" -Value $mailboxstate.totalitemsize
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ArchiveDatabase" -Value $mailboxonly.ArchiveDatabase
        $inpObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ArchiveSizeenter image description here" -Value $mailboxstateA.TotalItemSize
        $report += $inpObj
    }

$report
```

Thank for the help!